# Remove Empty Fields in Select Statement

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

I have a select statement as follows:

```
SELECT
    firstName,
    lastName, 
    CASE
        WHEN primaryEmail <> 'name@example.com' THEN primaryEmail
        WHEN secondaryEmail <> 'name@example.com' THEN secondaryEmail 
        ELSE ternaryEmail 
    END AS email
FROM participant 
WHERE 
    primaryEmail <> 'name@example.com' 
    OR secondaryEmail <> 'name@example.com' 
    OR ternaryEmail <> 'name@example.com'
```

The problem is that there are some records with empty fields, either firstName, lastName, or the resulting email. I added this to the WHERE clause:

```
firstName IS NOT NULL
AND lastName IS NOT NULL
AND primaryEmail <> // The already existing WHERE clause code.
```

but those fields still show up. I haven't bothered trying to get rid of the email part yet, so there's no code for me to show there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT
        firstName,
        lastName, 
        CASE
            WHEN primaryEmail <> 'name@example.com' THEN primaryEmail
            WHEN secondaryEmail <> 'name@example.com' THEN secondaryEmail 
            ELSE ternaryEmail 
        END AS email
    FROM participant 
    WHERE 
        (primaryEmail <> 'name@example.com' AND primaryEmail IS NOT NULL) OR
        (secondaryEmail <> 'name@example.com' AND secondaryEmail IS NOT NULL) OR
        (ternaryEmail <> 'name@example.com' AND ternaryEmail IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Why would this not return results if I want to specify a name?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: If I add something like and lastName = 'Smith', I don't get any different results.

Comment: If you were to append: OR (lastName == 'Smith') then in addition to the previous data set returned, you will also receive any data where the last name matches Smith. Is this not happening?

Comment: No. I get all data from the table that I had before adding the name.

Comment: Okay. Can you post the full query you're using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94453/discussion-between-cody-harness-and-carlosb).

Answer (score 0):

You need `or` logic, not `and`

```
where 
(firstName is not null or lastName is not null)
and other conditions
```

Comment: Still doesn't give me results. The value of the property might actually be '', but when I added or firstName <> '' nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a tricky one in T-SQL. I did find an answer to this question as well as learned exactly how the compiler looks at each "type" of Blank space or NULL.

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/09/06/How_does_SQL_Server_really_store_NULL-s.aspx